# Adding Spring Security to Existing Spring AngularJS Application

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-security

I am developing a web application using AngularJS and Spring (4.1.0.RELEASE) as the backend.  Everything is currently working great.  Now that the functionality is done, I would like to add Spring Security (3.2.5.RELEASE) to the project, to both authenticate, and then authorize all of the requests.  As I am using Angular, all of my views are static, and never rendered by the server.  Therefore, the typical Spring Security setup (with a login jsp), will not work.  I have looked at many examples, and none fit my needs.  I do not want to use any external frameworks like Jersey to help with the authentication, or any server-rendered views, e.g. jsps.

When I enable Spring Security, my GET requests still work fine, but my POST requests, such as my login requests, no longer work, and return a 404 error.  The controllers are correctly mapped, and the URLs are valid, so I know it must have something to do with Spring Security intercepting the request and deeming it invalid.  I am not sure why this is, but I think it may have something to do with the requests not having the proper headers and Spring's CSRF protection.  I do not want to disable this protection.  My question is, how can I define a custom login url with Spring Security, that will authenticate my login POST request, and then send back all headers necessary to enable future, authenticated requests?

EDIT: I have gotten the url to work.  Is there any way to retrieve the CSRF token from an ajax call?  My views are all static, and the server is first hit on the login request, so there are no jsps, and no way to get the csrf token from the server via the jsp tag libraries.  The suggestion in the first answer assumes that we are on a jsp, which is not the case.  Is there any way to allow CSRF protection, or do I need to disable it and perform my own request validation?

Comment: Myself also looking answer for your question. thanks for posting here!

Comment: Sounds like the way you are making call to the Post methods may be faulty, can you show the code that you are working with?

Comment: The methods were working fine before Spring Security was added, so I know it isn't anything to do with those.  It's something to do with Spring Security

Answer (score 0):

With Spring security enabled, you'll need to add the CSRF token to all POST, PATCH, PUT and DELETE requests. This can be sent in a request header and you should be able to use a GET request to get the token. The default header is `X-CSRF-TOKEN=<tokenvalue>`.

Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html
(This is an older version of the docs, but includes a very relevant section on Ajax and Json requests.)

If you want to disable CSRF protection for a specific URL, you'll need to write a custom RequestMatcher that excludes your login URL.
 In XML configuration it would look like:

```
<csrf request-matcher-ref="myCustomRequestMatcher"/>
```

See: http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2014/04/customizing-csrf-protection-in-spring-security/

Comment: Thanks, I know I need to add that to all post requests, but my question is about the login url.  The client has no interaction with the server until the login ajax call, so there is no way to get a csrf token.  Also, there is nothing in that link about getting the CSRF on an html page, those are all using jsp tags, which my application neither uses nor supports.